# multiple JSON fields named exception in “RELEASE” build mode only

Tags: android, gson, proguard, retrofit2

This is weird but **serialization is done perfectly fine in DEBUG build mode as well as in all of the API responses except one**. But in release mode, it's throwing illegal argument exception.

Here is the complete log for this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sampleapp, PID: 30480 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sampleapp/com.example.sampleapp.activity.ManageStoreActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.sampleapp.model.seller.SellerStoreFormData
  for method ApiInterface.getSellerInfoData
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.sampleapp.model.seller.SellerStoreFormData
  for method ApiInterface.getSellerInfoData
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
  at $Proxy0.getSellerInfoData(Unknown Source)
  at com.example.sampleapp.connection.a.i(Unknown Source)
  at com.example.sampleapp.activity.ManageStoreActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    ... 9 more


 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.sampleapp.model.seller.SellerStoreFormData declares multiple JSON fields named f
  at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Unknown Source)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

**What I have tried so far ?**

1. I have tried and looked for multiple JSON fields in same and parent
   class but didn't find any.
2. Checked that the @SerializedName is different for each field.

**I also have proguard enabled in release mode.**

It was working fine earlier (without enabling proguard) and I was not getting any compile time error.

Comment: You have two `JSON` fields with same name in model `SellerStoreFormData`

Comment: @aksacha i have checked it multiple times but could not find any.

Comment: not even in the parent model

Comment: show your `SellerStoreFormData` model code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If debug mode is working and release is the problem most chances is that's a proguard issue. 
Try excluding SellerStoreFormData from obfuscation.

Also, check if you have [proguard Gson configuration](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) in place and if not add it.

Comment: Thanks i already have maintained a proper proguard file . But updating it works. It was silly as missing semicolon. The message might be misleading because of proguard configuration.